# Failed to send Email via Exm Automated Campaign using sitecore form

Tags: exm

I created a sitecore form and trigger an automated email campaign through the form submit action.But it failed to send mail, and when I looked at the log file I got the following message.so can anyone help me to resolve this?
[image]

Comment: which Sitecore version you're using?

Comment: i am using sitecore 9.3

Comment: from the logs, seems like it has sent an email to 34 recipients. Just make sure the rest of the recipient have a valid email or known contacts in Sitecore. You'll need to map the value provider field on email to make this contact known.